# How do the USS Kelvin and USS Enterprise compare?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

Rewatching the film and reading through the wikis I'm a bit confused about the Kelvin. When comparing them, the Kelvin seems smaller (but seems to have a similar sized shuttlebay) and better armed.

**Is that correct or am I mistaken?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The excellent [Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/stxi_ships.htm) website offers a wealth of detail about the various ships seen in the Star Trek universe.

### Ship size

**The USS Kelvin**

- approx 315m from stem to stern.

**Reboot Enterprise**

- (officially) 366m from stem to stern.

It's worth noting that there's some [controversy over the size of the Enterprise](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/new_enterprise_comment.htm#size) as seen in the film, largely because of the liberties taken by the filmmakers in creating such a vast shuttlebay for the iconic landing scene.

---

### Weaponry

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelvin_type) offers an overview of the armament of each vessel

**USS Kelvin**

- 3 x Rapid-fire photon torpedo launchers
- 6 x (Pop-up type) dual phaser banks

**USS Enterprise**

- 2 x Rapid-fire photon torpedo launchers
- 5 x Rapid-fire phaser banks

Don't let the relative similarity in terms of armament numbers fool you. The Enteprise seems to be capable of rapidly-firing its phasers on a nearly continuous basis for a whole minute and unleashing photons in very large numbers.

Comment: So the phasers though less are stronger for the enterprise  only thing that seems to be stronger for the kelvin is then the torpedoes?

Comment: @thomas - The Enterprise seems to have much stronger phasers. Their photons are the same strength but they can fire them about five times faster. It pretty much outclasses the Kelvin in every facet except leadership (the Kelvin is run by a decorated and highly experience captain whereas the Enteprise is run by an Academy dropout and his mentally unhinged First officer)

Comment: thehe. one has to wonder though why the bay for the torps on the enterprise is that huge and the kelvin has turret launchers what is more effective but not part of this question though

Comment: @Richard - he's not mentally uninged. He's emotionally compromised

Comment: @DVK - I'll give you that one. Kirk's still a massive liability though, right?